Quadric surface fibration over $\mathbb{P}^2$ with a rational section and plane sextic curves
In the theory of special cubic fourfolds, it is known that, one way to construct a rational smooth cubic fourfold $X$ containing a plane is to have a quadric surface fibration $\tilde X \to \mathbb P^2$ that admits a rational section (or some Brauer class vanishes). On the other hand, quadric surface fibrations $\tilde X \to \mathbb P^2$ by are in bijective correspondence with plane sextic curves. The latter have very explicit equations $f(x_0,x_1,x_2) \in \mathrm{H}^0(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(6))$.
So what can one say about the equation of the sextic curve which produces a quadric surfaces fibration with rational sections?

It is not true that a quadric surface bundle over the plane is determined by its discriminant curve.
